# xml/xslt tag missing when it’s not

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

So after hours, literally, trying to solve a problem with xml/xslt, while following an online lesson, mind you, I’m dumbfounded and stuck utterly.

Does anyone have a really good working understanding of xml/xslt that they could help me see what I’m not seeing.

The issue I’m running into is I’m getting error messages of closing tags missing when they are not in fact missing.  Has anyone else ran into this kind of issue?

Comment: Applying https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example should help you to enable us to try to help you.

Comment: An XML parser will not lie about a missing end tag, but it won't always report the issue in an easy to interpret manner.  Reduce your code and XML to the smallest reproducible example that you can, [edit] your question, and add the example so that we can tell you specifically where your problem is.  (See also [mcve] and [ask].)  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you have overlapping tags .. <b>...<i>...</b>...</i> is invalid.